# Returning a String from function and calling it again in C

Tags: c, string, function

I'm using the function below to append a '>' to a string. When I call the function it works fine the first time, however, every time after that, instead of creating a new string with one of these brackets '>' appended, it keeps appending to the original string. How do I stop it from doing this?

```
/home/user >
/home/user > >
/home/user > > >   etc


Char * get_prompt(){
    char *pwd;
    pwd = getenv("PWD");
    strcat(pwd, " >");
    return pwd;
}
```

Comment: you're modifying the same string each time. `getenv` returns a pointer to string, which you modify. Next time you get back you're mdoified version. You need to copy the string before the `strcat`.

Comment: Thanks :D I don't know how to give you the points in a reply comment.

Answer (score 1):

It is not safe to modify the string returned by `getenv`. Instead you must copy the string and then append to it:

```
char *pwd = malloc( sizeof( char ) * MAX_LEN );
strcpy( pwd, getenv("PWD") );
strcat( pwd, " >" );
return pwd; // remember to free this memory.
```